# How can I run only defined detectors in find-sec-bugs

Tags: java, findbugs, find-sec-bugs

I'd like to run a findsecbugs scan (CLI version) against multiple jar and I only want it to check for issues related to bad usage of crypto functions (like using md5). 
How can I tell findsecbugs to only use detectors defined by me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The CLI is wrapping [SpotBugs official CLI](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running.html#command-line-options). All SpotBugs options will be available in the FindSecurityBugs CLI. You can use the `-include` parameter to define a filter file. [Filter files](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html) can be used to define which detector or class should be considered.

`findsecbugs.sh -include include.xml [...]`

Other references:

1. https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/wiki/CLI-Tutorial
2. https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/wiki/Maven-configuration